# boost fast pool allocator slower with pointer Vs. object

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I was trying to measure how fast is boost fast pool allocator for inserting a million objects in std:queue Vs. inserting a million pointers of the same object in std::queue. I expected inserting pointers to be much faster since inserting objects involves alot more copying when the queue.push() method is called. But I see the opposite when I run the following code:

```
 struct DepthData
{
    const char*     _symbol;
    double          _price;
    bool            _isAdd;
};

struct QueueData
{
    enum eQueueData { DEPTH, EXECUTION };

    int*        _strategy;
    eQueueData  _eQueueData;
    union
    {
        DepthData _d;
        // Add more later
    }   _type;

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    std::cout<< " " << sizeof(QueueData) << " " << sizeof(QueueData*);

    typedef boost::fast_pool_allocator<QueueData, boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete, boost::details::pool::default_mutex, 2000000*sizeof(QueueData), 0> FastAllocT;
    std::queue<QueueData, std::deque<QueueData, FastAllocT> > cq2;
    struct timespec startime2;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &startime2);
    for (double i; i< 1000000; ++i)
    {
        QueueData q2;
        cq2.push(q2);
    }
    struct timespec endTime2;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &endTime2);
    std::cout<<" "<<endTime2.tv_nsec-startime2.tv_nsec;
    boost::singleton_pool<boost::fast_pool_allocator_tag, sizeof(QueueData)>::purge_memory();

    typedef boost::fast_pool_allocator<QueueData*, boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete, boost::details::pool::default_mutex, 2000000*sizeof(QueueData*), 0> FastAllocT2;
    std::queue<QueueData*, std::deque<QueueData*, FastAllocT2> > cq3;
    struct timespec startime3;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &startime3);
    for (double i; i< 1000000; ++i)
    {
        QueueData* obj = NULL;
        cq3.push(obj);
    }
    struct timespec endTime3;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &endTime3);
    std::cout<<" "<<endTime3.tv_nsec-startime3.tv_nsec;
    boost::singleton_pool<boost::fast_pool_allocator_tag, sizeof(QueueData*)>::purge_memory();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is the following:
40 8 8957929 14162703

The 3rd no. (i.e. 8957929) is time taken to insert a million objects and 4th no. (i.e. 14162703) is time taken to insert a million pointers. I can't explain why it takes longer to insert pointers (especially mine are just NULL pointers!) ?!

I'm running this on CentOS and built the code using CMAKE Release build type using gcc version 4.8.5.

Comment: I'd suggest doing a couple of additional experiments: have q2 value constructed (just add a {} before the semicolon), have obj default-initialized (don't assign it to anything). The extra time may just be setting the obj to null, or the compiler detecting the undefined behavior of pushing an uninitialized q2 and doing whatever it wants there.

Comment: You don't cope with the timespec wrapping around the end of a second, so you should fix that. Also: try reversing the order of the two, and see if the first one is always faster. Run multiple times with just one or the other, and see how stable the times are.

Comment: its always the pointer insertion code that takes longer than object insertion regardless of the order. the times look pretty stable.

Comment: any other suggestions guys?